# TableViewCell updating incorrectly - iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, datepicker

I have a custom cell with a DatePicker, when the user clicks the cell, the cell expands to its full view showing the date picker (I have attached an image of the custom cell). I am trying to update the start time based on the date picker selection.

When I change the time in datepicker:
- for the first time it updates the date correctly
- Second time goes back to it's original value

Could someone please suggest, how I could fix this issue ?

```
class DailyTimesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var startTime: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    @IBAction func timePickerChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {

        startTime.titleLabel?.text = convertDateToString(sender.date)

    }
   func convertDateToString(_ dateObject: Date) -> String{
        let dateFormatter           = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
        let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: dateObject)
        return dateString
    }
}
```

Below is the gif showing the Error

[image: error]

Below is the custom cell

[image: customCell]

Comment: Problem is here - convertDateToString(), share that also

Comment: You put your code inside you custom tableview cell class? Wouldn't you encounter trouble if the cell dequeues itself? If you're not reusing views why not create it in a static tableview?

Comment: @KrunalBhavsar added convertDateToString() function as well

Comment: @JoshuaVidamo I'll try with your suggestion

Comment: dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short  >> replace this line with >> dateFormatter.format = "hh:mm a"

Comment: @KrunalBhavsar tried it, the problem persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the title of the button with the following method.

`func setTitle(String?, for: UIControlState)`

I replicated the problem and resolve by replacing the line

`startTime.titleLabel?.text = convertDateToString(sender.date)`

with

`startTime.setTitle(convertDateToString(sender.date), for: .normal)`

This is a very common mistakes I make many times.

Comment: It works when I replaced method `titleLabel` with `setTitle`